# Excel - Compare two cells and display the larger number?

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison, conditional-statements

Can someone tell me how to compare two cells (numbers), and then display the larger cell?

Cell C1 = IF A1 > B1 then display A1 else display B1

Sorry I'm not an excel pro.

Comment: Nevermind - I answered my owned question after kicking it around a bit - relatively easy thanks!

Comment: can you please add your answer here for future users.

Comment: @BoCh Yes, please add what you did as an answer, or, if someone else has suggested what you did, mark their answer as accepted

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but if someone else is having trouble:
The MAX(number1;number2;...) function is what you're looking for.
"Returns the largest value in a set of values. Ignores logical values and text."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the function IF you have to write the formula as follows and obtain the same result:
=if(A1>B1;A1;B1)

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(A>C,B,D)
```

If `A` is Greater than `C` return `B` else return `D`

```
A=50
B=1650
C=55
D=1870
```

Copy formula in cell you want the return value in.